# How to make asp.net mvc convert an array of strings to an array of value types when model binding?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Our system has a set of known "Contract Types" which have a code and a name.

```
public struct ContractType {
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have an MVC controller with a method like this.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search(SearchOptions options) {
   // returns search results
}
```

`SearchOptions` contains many parameters (including an array of `ContractType`)

```
public class SearchOptions {
  public ContractTypes[] Contracts { get; set; }
  // other properties
}
```

I would like asp.net MVC to automatically translate the contract type codes into an array of contract types on the `SearchOptions` model. For example, I want the MVC model binder to take a a querystring like this...

```
http://abc.com/search?contracts=ABC&contracts=XYZ&foo=bar
```

and populate `SearchOptions` so that it looks like the following data structure

```
{
  Contracts : [
    { Code : "ABC", Name: "ABC Contract Name" },
    { Code : "XYZ", Name: "XYZ Contract Name" }
  ],
  // other properties
}
```

I have a method available which will accept a contract type code and return the appropriate ContractType.

```
public ContractType GetContractTypeByCode(string code) {
 // code which returns a ContractType
}
```

I am not clear on whether I need to be using a custom model binder or a value provider. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use ModelBinder. Something like this

```
public class SearchOptionsDataBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
  public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
  {
    if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(SearchOptions))
    {
      var baseResult = (SearchOptions)base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
      var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

      baseResult.Contracts = request.QueryString
                                    .GetValues("contracts")
                                    .Select(GetContractTypeByCode)
                                    .Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Code))
                                    .ToArray();
      return baseResult;
    }

    return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);        
  }
}
```

And then add custom model binder to Application_Start:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(SearchOptions), new SearchOptionsDataBinder());
```

Comment: Thank you so much. There were a few problems with the code that I was able to iron out, but your basic solution worked like a charm.  I edited your answer with the code I ended up using.

Comment: Glad to help. 
Also maybe it is better to put check for empty value before select so you don't pass any empty values to GetContractTypeByCode method. 
                                    .Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c)).Select(GetContractTypeByCode)

Comment: My implementation of `GetContractTypeByCode` will currently return a `ContractType` instance with null value for the `Code` if it isn't a valid contract type.  Kind of weird I know. I should clean that up.

Comment: Can be the string property "contracts" replaced by some code which means the name of property in the model?